# Want to get relational table value in specified way in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I have 2 table like below.

**Table A**

```
id  | val_a
1   | a1
2   | a2
3   | a3
```

**Table B**

```
id  | id_a| val_b
1   | 2   | b1
2   | 2   | b2
3   | 3   | b3
```

What is the best way to get data like below :

```
    [
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id_a] => 1
            [val_a] => 'a1'
        )
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id_a] => 2
            [val_a] => 'a2'
            [table_b] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id_b] => 1
                            [val_b] => 'b1'
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                         (
                            [id_b] => 2
                            [val_b] => 'b2'
                         )
                )
        )
        [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id_a] => 3
            [val_a] => 'a3'
            [table_b] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id_b] => 3
                            [val_b] => 'b3'
                        )
                )
        )
]
```

I am using `Laravel 5.2`. And achive this by foreach loop. But I don't know what is the best way to do. Can I do this by laravel or Mysql ? Thanks Ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using Eloquent Model and `hasMany` relationship

for the first table `Table A`

```
class table_a extends Model
{   //define your primary key
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_a'; /*you can skip this if id is your primary key*/
    public function get_b_values(){
        return $this->hasMany(table_b::class, 'id_b', 'id_a');
        //foreign_key then local_key
    }
}
```

for the second table `Table B`

```
class table_b extends Model
{   
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_b';
    /*you can skip this if id is your primary key*/

}
```

Then you can access the element (exp id=2) you want like this:

```
table_a::find(2)->get_b_values;
```

### UPDATE

Try this in your controller:

```
$results=table_a::with('get_b_values')->get();
```

Comment: thank for code but this code not return required array.

Comment: Thank u so much. Love u :-)

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can do it using laravel, take data from table_a and store row in a variable and run another query in table_b where id_a = id (table_a's id column) and store them into your defined variable.

Comment: A subquery in a table? What's that?

Comment: this is simplest way to do but in case of multiple tables like this then it is very hard to do.

Comment: I feared as much. This is woefully inefficient!